# bash or perl inline capture of multiple pattern matches

Tags: bash, perl, ansible, confluence

Simple thing :

```
content='"id":"1234"abcdefg"id":"3456"'
```

need to get the id's out:

```
perl -le '@m = ( $content =~ /\"id\"\:\"(.*)\"/g); print for @m'
```

Not working but need a one liner for use on confluence json/output for processing by Ansible.

Comment: What are the ids exactly: `id`, `1234`, `"1234"abcdefg"`, ...? Please add your expected output. You can improve your question even further by using code formatting for code, and removing the tags [ansible] and [confluence] – the real question is only about [perl] and/or [grep].

Comment: Wondering _how_ do you gut such "strange" `content`. The `abcdefg` sure isn't JSON in your real app? (e.g. like `"id":"1234","some":"blaba","id":"3456"`)

Comment: Ansible does have a slightly fruity output format though, that's sort of a mishmash of 'stuff' with inlined JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Perl:

```
perl -sE 'say for $str =~ /"id":"(.*?)"/g' -- -str="$content"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
grep -Po 'id":"\K.*?(?=")' <<< "$content"
```

`-P` enables perl regexes.
`-o` prints only the matching parts instead of whole lines.
`\K` lets grep forget that it matched `id":"` before.
`.*?` matches as few caracters as possible ...
`(?=")` ... until a `"` is the next character. The `"` will not be included in the match.

Output for your example:

```
1234
3456
```